# Cannot install Entity Framework 6.1.3 in Visual Studio 2015 ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget, visual-studio-2015

When I'm trying to install EF 6.1.3 on class library project in Visual Studio 2015 RTM  I face this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

> Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'entityframework.6.1.3'
>    with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>
> Resolving actions to install package
>   'entityframework.6.1.3'
>
> Resolved actions to install package 'entityframework.6.1.3'
>
> Install failed. Rolling back... Package
>   'EntityFramework 6.1.3' does not exist in project 'xxx.DataAccess'
>
> Package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' does not exist in folder
>    'xxx\packages' install-package :
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At line:1 char:1
>   + install-package entityframework
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

My project target framework is 4.5.2 and windows ver is 10.

Comment: The NullReferenceException you get here is very generic, if the problem resides, try installing EF 6.1.2 in the Package Manager Console typing:

Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.2 

Also, you should update VS 2015 RTM with the newest updates and try installing Extensions such as EF Power Tools, as Your VS 2015 RTM might be missing some features.Note that a RTM will often contain some errors as it is considered new software and new software usually contain some few bugs. However, your error stack trace says that the package EF 6.1.3 does not exist.

Comment: Also try this: Download the EF 6.1.3 package directly from: 

http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework 

Now, click the "Download" link. And then copy the nuget file (unzip it) to the following folder (.nupkg), considering your user is called GIJane to:

C:\Users\GIJane\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache

Now run: Install-Package EntityFramework

Entity Framework is Microsoft Technology and should work with VS 2015 RTM.

Comment: I installed [EF Power Tools](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/) extension on VS 2015 and the cause of error is this extension. Thanks @ToreAurstad .